# CORS 502 Bad Gateway Error - ReactJS + FastAPI + AWS

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cors, fastapi

I have my frontend (ReactJS) and backend (Python FastAPI) deployed separately on AWS. I keep getting this error message in my console when I open my frontend in Chrome and access my backend APIs:

> Access to fetch at 'https://private-backend-url.awsapprunner.com/test'
> from origin 'https://private-frontend-url.amplifyapp.com' has been
> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
> needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
> CORS disabled. POST https://private-backend-url.awsapprunner.com/test
> net::ERR_FAILED 502 (Bad Gateway)

When running my backend and frontend separately on localhost, I see no issues at all.

My FastAPI middleware is as follows:

```
origins = ["http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000", "https://private-frontend-url.amplifyapp.com", "http://private-frontend-url.amplifyapp.com"]

middleware = [
    Middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=['*'],
        allow_headers=['*']
    )
]

app = FastAPI(title='Test API', middleware=middleware)
```

My ReactJS API Call is as follows:

```
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://private-backend-url.awsapprunner.com/test' ,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            ...newMessage,
            file: docName,
          }),
        }
      );
```

Upon inspecting element on Chrome, here are the relevant headers captured by the browser:

```
Request URL: https://private-backend-url.awsapprunner.com/test  
Request Method: POST  
Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway  
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin  
content-length: 0  
server: envoy  
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2509 
Accept: */*  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br  
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9  
Connection: keep-alive  
Content-Length: 212 
Content-Type: application/json  
Host: https://private-backend-url.awsapprunner.com 
Origin: https://private-frontend-url.amplifyapp.com 
Referer: https://private-frontend-url.amplifyapp.com/
```

I have tried multiple approaches based on what I have found on stackoverflow and other sources, but to no avail. Would appreciate guidance - this issue is deeply frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: 502 means that the load balancer/first web server weren't able to contact the server behind it - in this case it seems like envoy weren't able to connect to your application. This seems to be an issue without AWS deployment; does it work if you make a direct request to the service using curl or your browser?

Comment: @MatsLindh the weird thing is that half the endpoints in the backend work, whereas the others do not. If it were a server issue, shouldn't all endpoints return 502 consistently? It does not work using curl/browser, but does work when run as is on localhost. Hope this helps?

Comment: Hey, is your code publicly available on github so that I can have a deeper look at it. Also, as you AppRunner is private and we cannot access it, can you please provide its output when you try to access it : a. directly from any instance running in the same subnet b. from localhost:3000

Comment: @GurpreetSingh sorry, the code is not public. AppRunner just says "Illegal Operation". Inspecting network traffic on Chrome is what revealed the CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup proxy in React.

Either use `proxy` setting by adding below line to your `package.json`. Check if I have given the correct url.

```js
"proxy": "https://private-backend-url.awsapprunner.com",
```

Or, you can use this library `http-proxy-middleware` to create a middleware and rewrite the urls. I'd prefer this method as you can rewrite the urls however you like with a simple script like below. Remember you need to call your API endpoints with `/api` not with the full url in order this to work. Here is a sample code:

````js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api/*',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://private-backend-url.awsapprunner.com',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '/test'
      },
    })
  );
};```
````

Comment: Thanks - will check if this works shortly. Could you in the meantime please explain why a proxy is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your backend is running and is *accessible*. The 502 Bad Gateway error suggests that the server may not be running/not responding.
2. Make sure that the URL for your backend API is correct and is accessible from your frontend/browser.
3. Make sure the backend is serving correct response headers for CORS. The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header must be present in the response from your server. You make sure that you have the FastAPI route configured the same as you are adding middleware CORS configs. Also, localhost does not usually serve on HTTPS.
4. Try setting the "mode" property of the fetch request to "cors". This tells the browser to send a CORS request, which includes the "Origin" header in the request. You can do this as follows:

   ```
   const response = await fetch(
     'https://private-backend-url.awsapprunner.com/test' ,
     {
       mode: 'cors',
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
         ...newMessage,
         file: docName,
       }),
     }
   );
   ```
5. If you still cannot resolve the issue, you can try using a proxy server to forward requests from your frontend to your backend server. This can be done using server configs. such as Nginx/Apache, or AWS API Gateway.